# How to remove an HTML tag with PHPQuery?

Tags: html, phpquery

Update1: With the full source code:

```
$html1 = '<div class="pubanunciomrec" style="background:#FFFFFF;"><script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_slot = "9853257829";
google_ad_width = 300;
google_ad_height = 250;
//-->
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"> 
</script></div>';

$doc = phpQuery::newDocument($html1);
$html1 = $doc->remove('script');
echo $html1;
```

The source code is this the above. I have also read that exists a bug, http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/issues/detail?id=150 I don't know if it is solved.

Any clues on how to remove the <*script*> from this HTML?

Best Regards,

---

Hi,

I need to remove all <*script*> tags from a HTML document using PhpQuery.

I have done the following:

```
$doc = phpQuery::newDocument($html);

$html = $doc['script']->remove();
echo $html;
```

It is not removing the <*script*> tags and contents. It is possible to do this with PhpQuery?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This works:

```
$html->find('script')->remove();
echo $html;
```

This doesn't work:

```
$html = $html->find('script')->remove();
echo $html;
```

Answer (score 6):

From the documentation it looks like you would do this:

```
$doc->remove('script');
```

http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/wiki/Manipulation#Removing

EDIT:

Looks like there's a bug in PHPQuery, this works instead:

```
$doc->find('script')->remove();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. It is not working. Any more clues? Best Regards,

Comment: You should provide more information for people to test with. Can you supply the HTML?

Comment: Looks like there's a bug, I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

I was hoping something simple like this would work
pq('td[colspan="2"]')->remove('b');
Unfortunately it did not work as I hoped.
I ran across this stackoverflow and tried what was mentioned without success.

**This is what worked for me.**

```
$doc = phpQuery::newDocumentHTML($html); 
// used newDocumentHTML and stored it's return into $doc

$doc['td[colspan="2"] b']->remove(); 
// Used the $doc var to call remove() on the elements I did not want from the DOM
// In this instance I wanted to remove all bold text from the td with a colspan of 2

$d = pq('td[colspan="2"]');
// Created my selection from the current DOM which has the elements removed earlier

echo pq($d)->text();
// Rewrap $d into PHPquery and call what ever function you want
```